# Should I use async methods to select rows in my KendoUI Grids?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I'm having problems selecting rows on KendoUI Grids.  I have two grids that need to have pre-selected rows based on the data that's returned from the controller.  The problem is that the selection process is not working consistently because of, what seems to be, the data access time, that is the time it takes for the controller to return data which is requested via an ajax function client-side.

To test that theory, I placed an interval in the controller to stagger the returned data and it worked, but, again, it was not consistent.  Here is the code for the two grids:

***Vessel Grid***

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Vessel>()
    .Name("VesselGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Select().Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .PersistSelection()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(m => m.Id(x => x.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadVessels", "Core"))))
```

***Columns Grid***

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<VesselColumn>()
     .Name("columnGrid")
     .Columns(columns => {
         columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
         columns.Bound(p => p.ColumnName);
     })
     .Pageable()
     .Sortable(Sortable => Sortable.AllowUnsort(true))
     .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
     .Scrollable()
     .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
     .PersistSelection()
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
         .Ajax()
         .ServerOperation(true)
         .PageSize(20)
         .Model(m => m.Id(x => x.Id))
         .Read(read => read.Action("ReadVesselColumns", "Core"))))
```

Here is the ajax functions which are called on document ready which should pre-select the rows on each grid.

```
$(function () {     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Test/ReadUserVessels',
        data: { Id: 230 },
        success: function (data) {
            setVessels(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Test/ReadUserColumns',
        data: { Id: 230 },
        success: function (data) {
            setColumns(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });

    function setVessels(data) {
        $(data.vessels).each(function (vIndex, vValue) {
            $("#vesselGrid").getKendoGrid()._selectedIds[vValue.VesselId] = true;
        });            
    }
    function setColumns(data) {
        $(data.columns).each(function (cIndex, cValue) {
            $("#columnGrid").getKendoGrid()._selectedIds[cValue.ColumnId] = true;
        });
    }
})
```

Here are the controller actions that return data to these functions to highlight the rows.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ReadUserVessels(int? id) {
    IEnumerable<UserVessels> vessels = _userVesselService.GetUserVessels().Where(x => x.ViewId == id).ToList();
    return Json(new { success = true, vessels });
}
        
public async Task<JsonResult> ReadUserColumns(int? id) {
    IEnumerable<UserColumn> columns = _userColumnService.GetUserColumns().Where(x => x.ViewId == id).ToList();            
    return Json(new { success = true, columns});
}
```

As you can see, the page is loaded, when the document is ready two ajax calls are made at the same time to two controller actions.  From there the rows on the grid should be selected and highlighted in blue.  Only the vessels grid ever does this.

My guess was that, because of the requests going out, whatever process handles the selection of the rows on the grids, was still in use when the columns grid was asking to do the same thing.  This was a theory I tested by setting an interval on the controller action for the columns grid of 2 seconds.  It worked but it was inconsistent.

So, my question is, should I use async controller actions to access the data and if so, can someone help me with how that can be achived or is my approach incorrect?

Comment: What is the definition of `GetUserVessels()`?  Are you doing client-side filtering after returning all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your grid data isn't always populated by the time the document ready is firing, this is why you're seeing inconsistent behavior.

To resolve this, hook up the [databound event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) of your grids. The databound event will fire once all of the data is retrieved. Then, move your ajax calls (ReadUserVessels and ReadUserColumns) from document ready to the databound event handler for their respective grid.

Code example:

**Vessel Grid and js function**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Vessel>()
    .Name("VesselGrid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Select().Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .PersistSelection()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("vesselGridDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(m => m.Id(x => x.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadVessels", "Core"))))


<script>
  function vesselGridDataBound(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Test/ReadUserVessels',
        data: { Id: 230 },
        success: function (data) {
            setVessels(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I added code examples, did this change work for you? If so please remember to accept this answer!